# Math.Pow() broken in mono ARM build?

Tags: mono, arm, pow

So I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 on a BeagleBone (ARM 700MHz processor), and I just discovered, to my great surprise, that Math.Pow() returns incorrect results on that platform (Mono build 2.10.8.1ubuntu2.1).

After some searching, I found [this poster](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?p=188718) who indicates that this is a known issue. Almost casually. I'm a little shocked that a) the issue ever came up in the first place, and b) that there is no ETA on fixing what I view as a pretty fundamental bug in a core Math library.

Further searching only turned up a few hits, and nothing mentioning this on https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/ (I plan to submit a bug report).

So, admittedly without having gone into the source code yet (although I plan to),  can anyone explain to me the difficulties of fixing this, or how it could have been introduced in the first place?  I mean, the pow() function in math.h works as expected, so can't Math.Pow() just wrap that?  What am I missing here?

I guess I feel like there is something about floating point operations that underlies this that I don't understand, so this is more than just a bug report, I'd like to know what the fundamental problem is, or if it's just a big overlooked problem.

EDIT:
This page summarizes the root of the problem nicely (porting status of armhf in debian):
http://wiki.debian.org/ArmHardFloatTodo

Punchline: Mono 2.10 is listed as not fixed for the armhf port, but that it's in progress for mono 3.0.

Comment: It's a new linux platform using a community port of a microsoft language.  It's going to have kinks for a while.

Comment: It's probably something like that.  It just took me off guard that according to the post, there is no plan for a fix right away, which broke my mental model of "just go in and change 2 lines of code to make it right". I jumped to thinking it was tied to hardware difficulties in some way...

Comment: @Nikolay I'm not sure `math.pow` is a good tag. Have you consulted Meta before starting a tag spree? ;)

Comment: Nope, I didn't. Probably I should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some more detailed background on the problem:
http://lists.debian.org/debian-arm/2012/02/msg00000.html

But as a summary - armhf is not a properly supported ABI for Mono, the ARM port of which was made to the armel ABI. Meaning you end up with caller and callee disagreeing on where floating-point parameters are passed in function calls.

Very few things are "just change 2 lines of code", and those that are generally require substantial effort to track down which two lines are wrong, and what they should be doing instead.

Comment: Yeah, this is the root of it, also captured in this bug report: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=7938#c1. Didn't know much about that before, but I suspected it had to be something like this (less than supported hardware features).

Comment: That bug report now contains a link to a patch set - https://github.com/directhex/mono-1/commit/3a28afb60e21428dc6a773aaed5153f0dbef4f28 - said to enable this properly (and at a glance, it looks like it does).